# 1 to many relationship isn't resulting in what I'd expect

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first

In a scenario where a product can have many categories I'm trying to create this using code-first, I have a Product model which has a collection of Category like so:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

My Category looks like:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category(CategoryEnum @enum)
    {
        Id = (int)@enum;
        Name = @enum.ToString();
    }

    public Category() { }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Category(CategoryEnum @enum) => new Category(@enum);

    public static implicit operator CategoryEnum(Category category) => (CategoryEnum)category.Id;

}
```

Creating a migration then updating the database doesn't create a new table for this to join the 2 (Product and Category) together. I'd expect a new table with a `ProductId` and `CategoryId` but this isn't the case. Instead, it just creates a `ProductId` in the Category table?

How do I make EF create a table which joins the 2 together without having to create a new `DbSet<T>`

Comment: What you want is illogical. The relationship you've described is one-to-many and EF is behaving exactly as expected. There's no join table because `Product.Categories` represents the join directly. BTW, always initialize your collection properties: `ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new HashSet<Category>();`

Answer (score 1):

That is how it's supposed to be.
Example:
Product 1 Chicken
Categorie 1 Meat idProduct = 1
Categorie 2 Healthy idProduct = 1

etc...
You don't need another table for a relation one to many. The table is only usefull for many to many